# Upgrade to SQL Server 2017 Fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

- Windows Server 2016 - Fully Patched
- Sql Server 2016 SP2 CU3 -> Upgrade to 2017

**In place upgrade fails with error message:**

> Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL server error log for potential causes

**See this in the event log:**

> Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'ISServer_upgrade.sql' encountered error 917, state 1, severity 15. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.

I'm able to recover from backup, but I need to get this server upgraded.

What am I missing here?

Here is what I'll be trying in a bit (from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f45087d3-f581-4840-aba5-698112a0ebbb/upgrade-from-sql-server-2016-to-sql-server-2017-fails-on-script-isserverupgradesql-ssisdb?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade))

```
1) Execute Diff backup in SQL Safe
2) Create Snapshot in VCD
3) Perform Upgrade
4) When fails add -T902 flag to startup parameters
5) Start SQL Server
6) Install CU 11
7) Remove -T902
8) Start SQL Server
```

Comment: is sql server running as domain account ? If yes, try changing service account to `NT Authority\system` and proceed. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71797/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-check-the-sql-server-error-l/71798#71798 Also, post error sql server and windows logs.

Comment: Look at the errorlog and see what it's complaining about (the error occurring) and post that, please.

Comment: Recently I was on thread which helped OP solve similar issue. Please refer to [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217759/error-starting-sql-server-2017-service-error-code-3417/217762#217762) and [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219258/error-code-3417-after-installing-cu-for-sql-server-2016-sp1#comment430235_219258). Basically you have to locate SQL Server errorlog and post its content in the question. The errorlog would have reason why the script for the upgrade failed.

Comment: Sorry, the error log didnt have much other than what I already posted. Would seem there is an issue with the install process that is resolved in a later CU. Hopefully a SP will be issued soon to help us address this.

Answer (score 2):

Upgraded from sql 2014 standard edition to sql 2017 standard edition. Seems there is a bug in the initial 2017 edition for standard.

Used the steps ( as Wjdavis5 wrote and others )

- add -T902 to the startup parameters and started the service ! Great the service is starting
- Install CU 16  , this was the latest update in August 2019 ! All ok , CU 16 was installed successfully !
- stop SQL service and remote -T902. Restart Service ! All ok

In case a server restart is needed don't forget to restart

Comment: Had this problem from SQL 2016.  "Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'ISServer_upgrade.sql' encountered error 917, state 1, severity 15."  Apparently the RTM installer tries to do an online index rebuild in the SSIS database, which isn't supported by SQL Standard (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f45087d3-f581-4840-aba5-698112a0ebbb/upgrade-from-sql-server-2016-to-sql-server-2017-fails-on-script-isserverupgradesql-ssisdb)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what resolved the error, copied lovingly from a Microsoft forum

Here is what I'll be trying in a bit (from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f45087d3-f581-4840-aba5-698112a0ebbb/upgrade-from-sql-server-2016-to-sql-server-2017-fails-on-script-isserverupgradesql-ssisdb?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade))

```
1) Execute Diff backup in SQL Safe
2) Create Snapshot in VCD
3) Perform Upgrade
4) When fails add -T902 flag to startup parameters
5) Start SQL Server
6) Install CU 11
7) Remove -T902
8) Start SQL Server
```

The key here was to start up sql server with the -T902 parameter and then install the latest CU (which is 11 right now)